# Prestashop 1.7 Change quantities from INT to FLOAT

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I made the following:

1. In DATABASE I changed everywhere where quantities/qty/minimal_quantity column is present from INT to DECIMAL(17.2)

   - When adding a product and if I set to minimal quantity 0.22, it saves in DB 0.22
2. I changes In classes/controllers everywhere where quantities/qty/minimal_quantity is present from INT to FLOAT
3. I cleaned the cache

The problem is:

1. In Admin when saving product with decimal quantity it saves but after refresh is displays INT (however in DB it is decimal)
2. In Font it shows INT (if in DB it is 0.22 for minimal quantity in front office it is 0)

I did those modification successful on Prestashop 1.6.X But cant make it done in PRESTASHOP 1.7. Maybe someone who knows PS1.7 better knows where else I should look?

By the way, I checked all files in SRC folder...

Answer (score 0):

It's typed in Prestashop's core, you won't be able to do that in the DB directly, a solution to your need might be to overwrite on Prestashop's end the function (override/class/Product.php and override/class/stock folder) or just consider your float as an int and consider it a multiple of 100.

Comment: Apparently he modified all classes definition: `I changes In classes/controllers everywhere where quantities/qty/minimal_quantity is present from INT to FLOAT`.

Comment: yes I did all work in classes and controllers. I now look in theme JS for PS1.6 and 1.7. In ps1.7 they made one single JS file, and there is the problem... I think it will take some time until somebody will figure it out... Because the JS code is different. Comparinf Product.j for example and the theme.js it is totally different code